# Problems filtering xlsx and csv data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, xlsx

I have a problem regarding how to filter xlsx and csv data points with pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Wind.xlsx")
df.head()
filter = df[["WindSpeed"] > 2]
ew=df[filter]
print(ew)
```

How come it will not return the value greater than 2?

The result is an error which is the following:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
filter = df["WindSpeed"] > 2
```

Comment: I have already tried..
It will then return following error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @FrederikN.Pedersen your error would suggest that there are values in the windspeed column that are not numerical. What does df.dtypes return for that column?

Comment: The first row of the file is a header - may that be the problem?

Comment: Than probably you have to perform casting to 'int'

Comment: This should be because `Windspeed` is of type string. Try `filter = df["WindSpeed"].astype('int') > 2`.

Comment: "The first row of the file is a header - may that be the problem?" You can check it by looking at the output of `df.head()`.

Comment: Using the code you provided I got following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,4'

I then changed 'int' to 'float' then got following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,4'.

Could I just skip the first row maybe?

Comment: It looks like you are using comma as decimal separator, which is not default. Try `filter = df["WindSpeed"].str.replace(',', '.').astype('int') > 2`.

Comment: By changing 'int' to 'float' this worked perfectly - Thank you so much :)

Comment: My bad, I should have noticed that decimal digits implies float.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
filter = df[df['WindSpeed'] > 2]
```

Comment: I get following error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The problem is Windspeed is of type string so you need to convert it into type of int. So you should use  df[df['WindSpeed'].astype(int) > 2]

Comment: I have my answer. Thanks for your contribution :)